# Spark Dataframe: Group and rank rows on a certain column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, grouping, ranking

I am trying to rank a column when the "ID" column numbering starts from 1 to max and then resets from 1.

So, the first three rows have a continuous numbering on "ID"; hence these should be grouped with group rank =1. Rows four and five are in another group, group rank = 2.

The rows are sorted by "rownum" column. I am aware of the row_number window function but I don't think I can apply for this use case as there is no constant window. I can only think of looping through each row in the dataframe but not sure how I can update a column when number resets to 1.

> val df = Seq(
>     (1, 1 ),
>     (2, 2 ),
>     (3, 3 ),
>     (4, 1),
>     (5, 2),
>     (6, 1),
>     (7, 1),
>     (8, 2)
>   ).toDF("rownum", "ID")
>   df.show()

[image]

Expected result is below:
[image]

Comment: are you aware of lead lag functions? you can use it, to match to the previous one, check the previous row is 1 and current is not 1, then keep the same rank else increase by 1.

Comment: I used the lead window function and got the next row "ID" value; I also, understood what you said logic wise but not sure how to implement in Spark.

.withColumn("lead_col", lead(col("ID"), 1).over(Window.orderBy(col("rownum"))))

Comment: give me some time, will help you with a working one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with 2 window-functions, the first one to flag the state, the second one to calculate a running sum:

```
df
  .withColumn("increase", $"ID" > lag($"ID",1).over(Window.orderBy($"rownum")))
  .withColumn("group_rank_of_ID",sum(when($"increase",lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1))).over(Window.orderBy($"rownum")))
  .drop($"increase")
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+------+---+----------------+
|rownum| ID|group_rank_of_ID|
+------+---+----------------+
|     1|  1|               1|
|     2|  2|               1|
|     3|  3|               1|
|     4|  1|               2|
|     5|  2|               2|
|     6|  1|               3|
|     7|  1|               4|
|     8|  2|               4|
+------+---+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Prithvi noted, we can use `lead` here.

The tricky part is in order to use window function such as `lead`, we need to at least provide the order.

Consider

```scala
val nextID = lag('ID, 1, -1) over Window.orderBy('rownum)
val isNewGroup = 'ID <= nextID cast "integer"
val group_rank_of_ID = sum(isNewGroup) over Window.orderBy('rownum)

/* you can try 
df.withColumn("intermediate", nextID).show
//                           ^^^^^^^-- can be `isNewGroup`, or other vals
*/



df.withColumn("group_rank_of_ID", group_rank_of_ID).show

/* returns
+------+---+----------------+
|rownum| ID|group_rank_of_ID|
+------+---+----------------+
|     1|  1|               0|
|     2|  2|               0|
|     3|  3|               0|
|     4|  1|               1|
|     5|  2|               1|
|     6|  1|               2|
|     7|  1|               3|
|     8|  2|               3|
+------+---+----------------+
*/


df.withColumn("group_rank_of_ID", group_rank_of_ID + 1).show

/* returns
+------+---+----------------+
|rownum| ID|group_rank_of_ID|
+------+---+----------------+
|     1|  1|               1|
|     2|  2|               1|
|     3|  3|               1|
|     4|  1|               2|
|     5|  2|               2|
|     6|  1|               3|
|     7|  1|               4|
|     8|  2|               4|
+------+---+----------------+
*/
```

Comment: to use `Window`, one needs to `import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window`

Comment: Thanks, that is great idea.